# Replace all white spaces and / from a string

Tags: php

I'm able to replace all white spaces using the following code:

```
<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $value->getTitle().$opvalue->getTitle())) ?>
```

How can I also add the condition in the same line such that "**/**" will be also removed?

Comment: Read the manual: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: `str_replace(array(' ', '/'), '', $yourString);`. And, as Rizier123 said, rtfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(array(" ","/"), "", $value->getTitle().$opvalue->getTitle())) ?>`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

str_replace() can take an array, so you could do:

```
<?php echo strtolower(str_replace([" ","/"], "", $value->getTitle().$opvalue->getTitle())); ?>
```